# In R, how to convert a character of specific format into a date?

Tags: r

I have a character string that deals with time:

```
"2007-06-11T09:15:35Z"
```

However, I cannot convert this into date using the following command:

```
strptime("2007-06-11T09:15:35Z", paste("%y-%m-%d","T","%H:%M:%S","Z",sep=""))
```

I got the output as NA instead. What went wrong? How should I correctly deal with date and time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the correct format. `"%y"` is for 2-digit years (without the century). You need `"%Y"`.

```
R> strptime("2007-06-11T09:15:35Z", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
[1] "2007-06-11 09:15:35 CDT"
```